# How do I connect to a hidden WiFi network on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04

There doesn't seem to be such an option under the discovered networks. I never had this problem in 18.04 or previous releases, which all gave the option to connect to a hidden network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Wi-Fi Settings, click on the 3-dot menu, select **Connect to Hidden Network...**

[image]